# Making a matrix as sparse as possible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, sparse-matrices

Consider a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ where $n >> m$. In other words, $A$ has much more columns than rows. Also, consider we are given a fixed number (integer) $m \leq r < n$. I'm trying to find a matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times m}$ such that $B' B = I_m$ (i.e., $B'$ is the left inverse of $B$) and $BA$ is very sparse, as much as possible.

My first idea was to consider the case $r = m$ and take the $QR$ factorization of $A$. Then set $B = Q^T$ to get 
$$BA = Q^TA = Q^TQR = I_mR = R,$$ 
a triangular (and rectangular) matrix. This matrix has a few zeros in the first $m$ columns, but since $m$ is much smaller than $n$, there are a lot of non zero terms left. Also, in my context usually $r$ will be bigger than $m$ and smaller than $n$, so I don't want to choose specif values for $r$. I really want a general approach that maximizes the number of zero entries in $BA$ for a generic $r$ between $m$ and $n$.

I wonder if there is a better matrix to do the job. Hope you can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: You might start by trying to solve the simpler problem: Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, with $m < n$. What is $\mathrm{argmin}_{B \in {\mathbb{R}^{r \times m}}, \mathbf{rank}(B) \geq m} \mathrm{nnz}(BA)$?

Comment: @DrewBrady Is this a rethorical question? I don't know what is this argmin. Furthermore, I think the condition $B^TB = I_m$ automatically implies $rank(B) = m$, which is the maximal possible rank attainable.

Comment: Looks like you just rephrased my question. I can't see how simpler is your formulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pose the following optimization problem:
$$min_{C,B} \quad \|C\|_1 \qquad \text{s.t. } \quad C = BA.$$
An easy way to solve this problem is the [ADMM approach](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf). In summary, you add the augmented Lagrange multiplers:

$$L(C,B,\Delta) = \|C\|_1+\frac{\rho}{2}\|BA-C\|_F^2+Tr(\Delta^\top(BA-C)),$$
and alternatively update $C,B,\Delta$ until convergence.

The above approach is a general optimization framework and for generic values of $r$. But you need to choose $r$ beforehand, so I am not sure if it's applicable to your problem.